# How can I get the handle of a Simulink block in Matlab R2013b?

Tags: matlab, simulink

There is a function in Matlab R2018b, `getSimulinkBlockHandle`, but it doesn't exist in R2013b. I want to know how I can  get the handle of a Simulink block without this function. I need it to use the function `get(h,'parameters')`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`get_param`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html) and `set_param` with the block name instead of the block handle.

*EDIT*

It seems from the comments that the OP wishes to deal with Simulink annotations, rather than ordinary blocks. This is slightly more complicated because annotations don't have block names. Here's an example

```
% Open the "vdp" model
open_system('vdp');
% Find annotations
annotations = find_system(gcs,'FindAll','on','Type','annotation');
% Set the background colour to green for the first of these
set_param(annotations(1), 'BackgroundColor', 'green')
```

More here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-an-annotation-programmatically.html

Comment: Thank u Edric for ur answer but i searched for 'Color' as Parameter in get_param but i didnt find actually , i want to change the color of the text in block Simulink